# how is this function being actived through an id by using click()? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, click

I am a bit confused how does the following works?
I will post out the codes first,

**html**

```
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="guessInput" placeholder="A0" />
        <input type="button" id="fireButton" value="Fire!" />
    </form>
```

**js**

```
 function handleFireButton(){
    console.log("I am clicked");
}

function init(){
    var fireButton = document.getElementById("fireButton");
    fireButton.onclick = handleFireButton;

    var guessInput = document.getElementById("guessInput");
    guessInput.onkeypress = handleKeyPress;
}


function handleKeyPress(e){
    var fireButton = document.getElementById("fireButton");
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        fireButton.click();
        return false;
    }
}

window.onload = init;
```

What my question is, in it `init` I can understand the first part where `fireButton.onclick = handleFireButton;` this way it'll active the function when clicked but the second half is where I am bit confused.

I understand when `onkeypress` it'll active the `handleKeyPress` which passes the event object to check if the `keyCode === 13` if so `fireButton.click()` will be activated but nothing here mentioned anything about activating `handleFireButton()` how does it know when `fireButton.click()` it should go to the `handleFireButton()`?

Comment: Because it triggers the `click`event, which calls  `handleFireButton()` function

Comment: It looks to me that when you click the button, handleFireButton will fire.  If you press the key that is 13 then fireButton will click, also triggering handleFireButton.  So, what's the problem?

Comment: @durbnpoisn not having a problem :D just wonna clarify how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the same dom element that you have in both places. You first attached an event handler to the dom button. Now u are accessing the same button from dom. And are clicking it. Since the handler is already attached it is firing the handler.

Comment: ah ok, so that means if in my `init()` `fireButton.onclick = handleFireButton;` is not assigned then in `handleKeyPress()` the `fireButton.click();` would not work?

Comment: Exactly. U don't bind it u can't fire it.

Answer (score 3):

The `click()` function fires off a click event, which is picked up by any relevant event listeners. It essentially simulates the user clicking the element.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click):

> The HTMLElement.click() method simulates a mouse click on an element.
>
> When click is used with elements that support it (e.g. one of the `<input>` types listed above), it also fires the element's click event which will bubble up to elements higher up the document tree (or event chain) and fire their click events too. However, bubbling of a click event will not cause an `<a>` element to initiate navigation as if a real mouse-click had been received.

So, `fireButton.click()` isn't calling `handleFireButton()` directly, instead it is generating an event which the `handleFireButton()` onclick event listener is reacting to.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :D It's great! but I didn't put it as the answer just beceause Sunil mentioned it first.  Really sorry about it.  But really thanks.

Comment: Fair enough, although I think the best answers are the ones that are clear and concise rather than the ones that race to be first.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use jquery or plain JavaScript?

For jquery you can simply call the Funktion within click

```
fireButton.click(funktion(){fireButton handle()})
```

For plain JS you have to use the onclick function